# How do I recursively build a nested list from a json data?

Tags: json, recursion, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to build a nested list of nodes which should look like the expected result below:

`(html (head (meta title)) (body (ul (div) (div) (div)))` ; *I guess this is the right approach for an interface label*

This is the original data from `json-read-from-string`:

```
(pp json-dom)
((tag . "html")
 (children .
           [((tag . "head")
             (children .
                       [((tag . "meta")
                         (children .
                                   []))
                        ((tag . "title")
                         (children .
                                   []))]))
            ((tag . "body")
             (children .
                       [((tag . "ul")
                         (children .
                                   [((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))
                                    ((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))
                                    ((tag . "div")
                                     (children .
                                               []))])))))
```

I will be grateful if you can please assist in helping to obtain the correct result.

This is what I have done  so far:

Starting with the recursive function `sidetree`, I'm faced with either invalid argument when testing with `listp` or nil result when testing the top argument with `vectorp`

```
(defun sidetree (node) 
  (when (vectorp node) 
    (cons (cdr (assoc 'tag node)) 
          (sidetree 
           (assoc 'children node)
           ; (cdr (car (aref (cdr (assoc 'children json-dom)) 0)))
           ))))

(pp (sidetree json-dom))
nil"nil"
```

I tried using the `letrec` approach as well,

```
(defun fliptree()
(letrec
    ((untree (lambda (tr)
               (list
                (alist-get 'tag tr)
                (append (apply-partially untree '(alist-get 'children node)) nil )
                ))))
  (funcall untree json-dom))
)
```

And got the following result. I don't know what I'm not doing right.

```
(pp (fliptree))
("html"
 (128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207"
      [(closure
           ((untree closure #4
                    (tr)
                    (list
                     (alist-get 'tag tr)
                     (append
                      (apply-partially untree
                                       '(alist-get 'children node))
                      nil)))
            t)
           (tr)
         (list
          (alist-get 'tag tr)
          (append
           (apply-partially untree
                            '(alist-get 'children node))
           nil)))
       ((alist-get 'children node))
       apply append]
      6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"))
```

​

Comment: Your expected result looks weird. The final `div` should be inside `body`, shouldn't it? Where does `header` come from and why do you omit the `ul` and the other two `div`s?

Comment: ok, thanks let me ammend

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it's still not clear what the principle should be. The header looks straightforward enough, you extract exactly the structure from your input. Why is the body different, and how do you know which nodes to omit?

Comment: I have updated the expected result, can you please check?

Comment: Thanks. The input `json-dom` also lacks some closing parentheses, but we can guess what they should be. Still, please review the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: What else do you like me to amend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242670/discussion-between-afidegnum-and-tripleee).

Comment: Not in a place where I can debug this, but your `sidetree` function seems to assume a `vector` input, which your `json-dom` tree is not. I can get it to do something vaguely useful by replacing `(vectorp node)` with just `node` and traverse the `caddr` of the `children` but you should probably spend some more time debugging this on your own.

Comment: That will be fine

Comment: I have corrected the parentheses on the original data, can you please look at it again ?

Comment: Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to realise that you have nodes which have tags and children.  The tags are whatever they are (strings) and the children are sequences of nodes.  And you want to turn a node into a cons of its tag and the result of converting its children.

Implementationally nodes are alists, so we can write a couple of readers for the fields:

```
(defun node-tag (node)
  (cdr (assq 'tag node)))

(defun node-children (node)
  (cdr (assq 'children node)))
```

And then the function to do the conversion is very simple and obvious:

```
(defun node->html (node)
  (let ((tag (node-tag node))
        (children (node-children node)))
    (when (not tag)
      (error "Not a node: %s" node))
    (when (not (sequencep children))
      (error "broken children %s" children))
    (cons tag                           ;might want to make symbo;?
          (seq-map #'node->html children))))
```

And now, with your `json-dom`:

```
> (node->html json-dom)
("html"
 ("head"
  ("meta")
  ("title"))
 ("body"
  ("ul"
   ("div")
   ("div")
   ("div"))))
```

In real life you probably want to cope with children which are strings:

```
(defun node->html (node)
  (if (stringp node)
      node
    (let ((tag (node-tag node))
          (children (node-children node)))
      (when (not tag)
        (error "Not a node: %s" node))
      (when (not (sequencep children))
        (error "broken children %s" children))
      (cons tag                           ;might want to make symbol?
            (seq-map #'node->html children)))))
```

and now

```
ELISP> (node->html '((tag . "div")
                     (children .
                               [((tag . "p")
                                 (children . ["foo" "bar"]))])))
("div"
 ("p" "foo" "bar"))
```

And perhaps attributes:

```
(defun node-attributes (node)
  (cdr (assq 'attributes node)))

(defun node->html (node)
  (if (stringp node)
      node
    (let ((tag (node-tag node))
          (children (node-children node))
          (attributes (node-attributes node)))
      (when (not tag)
        (error "Not a node: %s" node))
      (when (not (sequencep children))
        (error "broken children %s" children))
      ;; elisp doesn't apparently have list*
      (cons tag (cons attributes
                      (seq-map #'node->html children))))))
```

and finally

```
ELISP> (node->html '((tag . "div")
                     (children .
                               [((tag . "p")
                                 (children . ["foo" "bar"]))
                                ((tag . "a")
                                 (attributes . (("href" "blah")))
                                 (children . ["a link"]))])))
("div" nil
 ("p" nil "foo" "bar")
 ("a"
  (("href" "blah"))
  "a link"))
```